# implement a C function to count two digit numbers

Tags: c, arrays, function, compiler-errors

I want to implement a C function to count two digit numbers 
(let's say in this array; `a[2][5]={{10,19,1,-6,4},{8,0,-9,99,45}}`)
This is the code that i wrote:

```
int count( int a[i][j], unsigned int k)  //the function
{
    int i,j;

    for (i=0; i<2;i++){
        for(j=0; j<5; j++){
            if(1 <= (a[i][j] /10) && (a[i][j] /10) <10) // the mistake is here!
              k++;
        }
    }

    return k;
```

but the compiler kept on saying that on the line 20 "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector"

I would appreciate help with this problem, and thanks in advance!

Comment: With the function parameter `int a[i][j]` the compiler does not know the dimensions of the array. Try `int a[][5]`. It is not even a variable length array, since `i` and `j` are uninitialised local variables.

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/7ABVWg) ?

Comment: Your computation seems like a long-winded way to test whether a value is between 10 and 99 inclusive (or that it's absolute value is in range).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you very much, it worked!...well part of the problem is that i HAVE to write the function on this form "count(int a[], unsigned int k)" would i have to use pointer?! Thanks a lot again :)

Comment: `int a[]` must be `int a[2][5]` or `int a[][5]` or `int (*a)[5]` (Also All of these are pointers.) because it is `int a[2][5]` on the caller side. Also, `k` does not have to be an argument. If you do this, you must pass 0 on the caller side.

Comment: _"subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector"_ This error seems to be because it is `int a[]`. If it is correct that the first argument is `int a[]`, then `int a[2][5]` must be such `int a[10]`. In this case, `k` is assumed to be the number of elements of one-dimensional array.

Comment: For example, you might be trying this way. `int a[2][5]={...}; count(&a[0][0], 10);`. (you are trying to pass a two-dimensional array as one dimension.) This will work as expected in most situations. However, this is not recommended. Because one dimensional array is guaranteed to be linear. But two dimensional array is not necessarily like that. (First, you need to make sure that the two-dimensional array is linear(There is no thing like padding).)

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/iau60G)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you very very much :D ! it was so helpful!...

Answer (score 0):

Use a double pointer instead, the essence of a 2-dimensional array is a double pointer.

```
int count( int **a, size_t k);
```

Comment: And I would suggest that you do not actually need to define k as a parameter. You can simply define it in the function to produce the return value.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yeah you're correct, there really are difference, but i guess it's enough for a starter ;-)

Comment: If you pass `a` (`int a[2][5]`) to your function it will not work properly.